# NodeJS load a json from a file selector without reloading webpage

Tags: html, node.js, file, selector, reload

Has anyone done this?

I need to be able to grab a JSON file from a input file selector from HTML, after that read it, parse it and show it in the webpage.

The page cannot reload and I don't need to upload/copy it to any of my folders. I just need to read it and show it without reloading the webpage.

Any ideas? I'm on Nodejs. I'm serving static html pages. Apparently it's simple but I'm struggling a lot.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="file" onchange='getContent(this)' />
<div id="file-content"></div>
```

JS:

```
function getContent(content) {
 if (content.files && content.files[0]) {
  var contentReader = new FileReader();
  contentReader.onload = function(e) {
   var output = e.target.result;
   document.getElementById('file-content').innerHTML = output;
  };
  contentReader.readAsText(content.files[0]);
 }
}
```

You can see live preview [here](https://codepen.io/zeybek/pen/abzyRwj)

Comment: OK, but how  do I capture this JSON to use it NodeJs (backend) to desearilize it ? I need to parse it to objects and show some parts in some divs. I don't now what is the approach here. Thanks for your answer, btw